# Keyup on multiple fields only activates on first field?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to have multiple input fields, and if you were to change any of the fields, all of the others would change accordingly.

However, using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".field").keyup(function(){
        $('.field').val(
            $('.field').val()
        );
  });
});
```

and all fields using the same class, only the first field will change all the others on input. Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I think That is because you are saying that change all values to `.field` value, & by default it will return the value of first element having `.field`. Anyone could correct me if I am wrong.

You should use this instead

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".field").keyup(function(){
        $('.field').val($(this).val()); 
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/e1oq05jt/1/)

Comment: +1 Correct: [`.val()` == Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.](http://api.jquery.com/val/)